# How to create array and initialize string values in python in one step?

Tags: python, string, list

How do I create an array and initialise the string values in python in a single step as below?

```
releases = ["11.3.0",  "8.0", "1.0.6", "1.0.5", "1.0.4", "1.0.3", "1.0.2", "1.0.1", "1.0.0", "1.0.3.0", "1.0.2.0" ]
```

And how do I access array elements?

Comment: there are many resources out there @shantha

Comment: `print releases[0]` returns `11.3.0`

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: *And how do I access array elements?*: Are you kidding?

Comment: I see don't any resource answering this question. Can please share a link?

Comment: how do I access array elements? It's the same in every programming language

Comment: @ShanthaD I've posted a link for you. You should really read some tutorials first before asking very simple questions. SO is for helping you with code, not teaching you to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) in python official tutorial.

This initialises the list:

```
releases = ["11.3.0",  "8.0", "1.0.6", "1.0.5", "1.0.4", "1.0.3", "1.0.2", "1.0.1", "1.0.0", "1.0.3.0", "1.0.2.0" ]

print releases
["11.3.0",  "8.0", "1.0.6", "1.0.5", "1.0.4", "1.0.3", "1.0.2", "1.0.1", "1.0.0", "1.0.3.0", "1.0.2.0" ]
```

you access elements like:

```
releases[0]
"11.3.0"

releases[5]
"1.0.3"
```